# How to access hyperlink attributes in jquery when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to customize a confirmation dialog with a custom message embedded in the hyperlink tag, something like this:

```
<a class="confirmation" href="whatever.html" data-message="Are you sure?">the text</a>
```

and the js:

```
$('.confirm-delete').click(function(){
    return confirm('the content of the data-message attribute');
});
```

So my question is how can I access the data-message attribute? Thanks!

Comment: can we use Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are using jQuery, so use the **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** function to get `data-*` attributes.

Also using simple JS `this.dataset.message` will work on most of the new browsers, but going back to primitive browsers, use `this.getAttribute('data-message')`. But in the case which you are using jQuery, `.data()` is preferred.

```js
$('.confirmation').click(function(){
  return confirm($(this).data('message'));
});

function message(element){
  return confirm(element.dataset.message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="confirmation" href="whatever.html" data-message="Are you sure?">Use jquery</a>
<br/>
<a href="whatever.html" onclick="return message(this);" data-message="Are you sure?">Use simple JS</a>
```

Comment: works great, thanks! I'll go with hte data option as long this is for an intranet and users have modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

use the `attr` method

```
$('.confirm-delete').click(function(){

   return confirm( $( ".confirmation" ).attr( "data-message" )  ); //return the message fetched from the data-message attribute 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
alert($(".confirm-delete").attr("data-message"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how:

```
$('.confirmation').click(function(){
   return confirm($(this).attr('data-message'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code :

```
<a class="confirmation" id="confirmlink" href="whatever.html" data-message="Are you sure?" onclick="callConfirm()">the text</a>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
    function callConfirm() {
        var linkval=document.getElementById("confirmlink");
        var attribval=linkval.getAttribute("data-message");
        alert(attribval);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, will show the attribute "data-message" when clicking the link.

```js
$('.confirmation').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).attr('data-message'));
return confirm('the content of the data-message attribute');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="confirmation" href="whatever.html" data-message="Are you sure?">the text</a>
```